# Function's parameter used inside a previously defined variable (String) returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, ethers.js, etherscan

trying to declare a variable for an API call (There are different website versions for API calls so want to have it dynamically interchangeable while having clean code).

It goes like this:

```
const getAbi = async (addy) => {
  const url = `https://api.arbiscan.io/api?module=contract&action=getabi&address=${addy}&apikey=${arbiscanKey}`;
  const abi = await axios.get(url);
  console.log(abi);
  return abi;
};
```

Now, its supposed to take the function parameter (Named "addy") and input it inside the API call link. For some reason, it does not do that. It gives me error:

```
const arbiscanGetAbi = `https://api.arbiscan.io/api?module=contract&action=getabi&address=${addy}&apikey=${arbiscanKey}`;
                                                                                            ^

ReferenceError: addy is not defined
```

Not sure how to get it to realise i am referring to "addy" from the function parameter, thanks!

Comment: to get the value of that constant you have to call that method, `let` and `const` have block-level scope, that will not be available outside of the method.

Comment: not reproducible here, there must a typo or something.